# Fetching the name of column which contains empty string " "

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find the name of the column that contains the empty string " "

```
for i in df.columns:
    print(i, '\t\t', df[df[i] == " "].index)
```

Here, I need to print the column name i, only for which the column contains empty string " "

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [' ', ' ',' '],
    'b': [' ', '', ' '],
    'c': [' ', '  ', ' ']
})
    
#test empty strings or whitespaces (0 or more)
L1 = df.columns[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(r'^\s*$')).all()].tolist()
print (L1)
['a', 'b', 'c']

#test whitespaces (1 or more)
L2 = df.columns[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(r'^\s+$')).all()].tolist()
print (L2)
['a', 'c']

#test whitespaces (1 only)
L3 = df.columns[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(r'^\s{1}$')).all()].tolist()
print (L3)
['a']
```

IIUC your solution:

```
for i in df.columns:
    if (df[i] == " ").all():
        print(i)
        a
```

Comment: Hi, It's returning an empty list, whereas my code returns the index no of empty values.

Comment: @Ajay - I add sample data, it expected ouput column `b` ? Or need something else

Comment: @jezrael the comment for L1, shouldn't it be "0 or more" ?